# How can I mod a Minecraft slime to be about the size of a full block?

Tags: minecraft-modding, bukkit

I want to make the slime's size roughly the size of a full block,
I have tried some values but I'm not sure if any of those I tried fit the idea I have.

What would you recommend for the size of the slime which roughly matches or matches a block's size?

Answer (score 3):

## You can't.

You can't make a "size" 1.8 slime. The closest you can get is a size 2 slime because [`Slime.setSize(int)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Slime.html) only takes an integer because the `Size` NBT tag within a slime only takes an integer too.

See [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/what-size-should-i-put-in-slime-setsize-to-roughly-match-a-blocks-size.506930/).